# Multiple dns suffix/search base on Windows DHCP

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, dhcp

I am trying to find out how can I give out more than one DNS suffix on a DC with the Windows DHCP server.
  Is it possible somehow? (Win 2K8 with XP, Win7 and Linux clients)

Comment: It sounds like this is what you're looking for: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd572752(v=office.13).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use DHCP option 119 for a domain search list.  It's format is a String which is semi-colon delimited (e.g. `mydomain.com;dev.mydomain.com`)

Related:

[Which DHCP Client OS Support DHCP Option 119 Domain Suffix Search?](https://serverfault.com/questions/37417/which-dhcp-client-os-support-dhcp-option-119-domain-suffix-search)

Comment: Thank you. A bit closer to the solution, but the win7 clients do not ask/ignore (haven't made a tcpdump yet) the 119. I read it is only work from GPO, but the clients are not logged into the AD, so I am stuck here

Answer (score 3):

Some DHCP servers have the ability to assign a DNS suffix search list to DHCP clients through the use of DHCP option 119; however, Windows Server does not support this functionality by default. Furthermore, Windows DHCP clients do not support option 119 at all. Option 119 can be created manually on a Windows DHCP server using the procedure listed in DHCP Search Options, but this will only provide a DNS suffix search list to non-Windows clients that support it. In short, there is no way to assign a DNS suffix search list to a Windows client using DHCP.

A DNS suffix search list can be assigned to domain-joined Windows machines via Group Policy by following the procedure in [Configure the DNS Suffix Search List for a Disjoint Namespace](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb847901%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).

Information source - [Unable to configure DNS suffix search list via DHCP @ Dell Knowledge base](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN291195/EN)

Answer (score 0):

If you have linux clients (and Macs) you can use DHCP option 119 Domain-search-list.  If you have a WIndows DHCP server then in the windows DHCP snap-in you'll find it in the server scope pre-defined options.  You have to add option 119 there.  You have to choose byte array and you have to enter the bytes of the search domains in a kind of weird pascal string format.  It's easier to enter them backwards in windows DHCP snap-in.

ex.com,am.com would be in hex:

```
02 0x065 0x78 03 0x63 0x6f 0x6d 0x00 0x02 0x61 0x6d 0x03 0x63 0x6f 0x6d 0x00
2bytes e x 3bytes c o m 0null 2bytes a m 3bytes c o m 0null
```

Windows clients will ignore this though.  For them you have to use a GPO.

It's much simpler with a linux DHCP server.