# Windows DHCP client and DNS suffix search list (option 119)

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, dhcp, internal-dns

I'm trying to supply the dns search list to my windows clients to make the internal DNS naming scheme usable.
Windows AD is not used so no GPO available.

The ideal way would be to supply the dns search list via DHCP option 119.
Windows DHCP clients tragically don't seem to support that.

Is there an alternative way of achieving this beside GPO?

Related:

[Which DHCP Client OS Support DHCP Option 119 Domain Suffix Search?](https://serverfault.com/questions/37417/which-dhcp-client-os-support-dhcp-option-119-domain-suffix-search)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? Maybe DHCP option 15 will suffice for your scenario?

Comment: I have an internal DNS naming scheme, e.g. <host>.<location>.intr.example.com. Option 15 supplies only one entry, so i can use only example.com or intr.example.com. What i'd like to be able to do is just use the 'host' part when accesing other hosts. The machines would have to know multiple DNS suffixes to perform the search...

Answer (score 1):

No Windows clients do not request DCHP option 119.

The only way to set multiple DNS search domains is through:

1. Group Policy
2. Registry
3. Manually

Comment: Related question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/37417/which-dhcp-client-os-support-dhcp-option-119-domain-suffix-search